# JSF dataTable to display a fixed number of rows

Tags: datatable, jsf-2, myfaces

Greetings,

The context is myFaces 2.0.2, possibly also adding Tomahawk 20-1.1.10

I have created a dataTable (currently an `h:dataTable`, but could also be a `t:dataTable` using Tomahawk) displaying certain attibutes of a `List<MyObject>` in a backing bean.  I have paging by returning only a `subList` of the List, and also sorting by click of column headers.

The next thing I need to do is ensure the table always shows a fixed number of rows.  For example, if my page size is 5 and I have 12 items in the List, I need page three to show the last two items, plus 3 blank rows.

I have tried to "pad" the `subList` with both nulls and instances of `myObject` with null values, but this led to `ConcurrentModificationException` when hitting the last page of the table (the view was trying to `getDisplayList` even as the paging method was still adding the extra values.).  I then tried padding the main list in the same manner, but then got `NullPointer`s on my sort functions (a no-brainer in hind sight).  Plus, these things are all addng overhead in the backer, when I would rather do this in the xhtml view.

`(h:/t:)dataTable` does have a `rows` attribute, but this specifies the maximum number of rows to display, not the minimum, as I need.

Ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pad the sublist. Pad the list. Preferably immediately after retrieving it in the bean.

Comment: You will note that this is one of the things I did attempt.  The result is NullPointer exception on the sort functions.  I am using anonymous inner Comparator classes, and the declaration of function "public int compare (MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2)" is where the exception is thrown if the objects themselves are null.  If the objects are not null but their values are, then exception is thrown inside this function when I have, say "return obj1.getStringValue().compareTo(obj2.getStringValue());"

Comment: Ah right. Then wrap the sublist in a `new ArrayList` and pad it instead right before returning to view.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to pad the MAIN List, rather than the subList, using objects which are not null but whose attributes are null, and to add a null check into the Comparator:

```
if (obj1.getSomeValue() == null) {
    return +1;
}
else if (obj2.getSomeValue() == null) {
    return -1;
}
else {
    // primary sorting code
}
```

Which ensures null items always come last.  Works perfect.

BalusC did give me the push in the right direction, so I am accepting his answer.